# How to get unique date range in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Here is my data rows:

```
       start_dte        |        end_dte
------------------------+------------------------
 2018-08-01 00:00:00+00 | 2018-08-05 00:00:00+00
 2018-08-03 00:00:00+00 | 2018-08-05 00:00:00+00
 2018-08-09 00:00:00+00 | 2018-08-10 00:00:00+00
(3 rows)
```

I want to get a result like this:

```
  [
    '2018-08-01',
    '2018-08-02',
    '2018-08-03',
    '2018-08-04',
    '2018-08-05',
    '2018-08-09',
    '2018-08-10',
  ]
```

How can I do this using `SQL`? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, but don't know whether or not it is a best way.

Here is my solution:

```
select 
  distinct generate_series 
from 
  results, 
  generate_series(results.start_dte, results.end_dte, '1 day'::interval) 
order by generate_series asc;
```

output:

```
    generate_series
------------------------
 2018-08-01 00:00:00+00
 2018-08-02 00:00:00+00
 2018-08-03 00:00:00+00
 2018-08-04 00:00:00+00
 2018-08-05 00:00:00+00
 2018-08-09 00:00:00+00
 2018-08-10 00:00:00+00
(7 rows)
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be the solution:

```
select 
  distinct generate_series(start_date, end_date, '1 day'::interval)::date 
from 
  my_table
order by 
  generate_series asc;
```

Output:

```
      generate_series  
 ------------------------  
"2018-08-01"  
"2018-08-02"  
"2018-08-03"  
"2018-08-04"  
"2018-08-05"  
"2018-08-09"  
"2018-08-10"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a series of dates using `generate_series`, and then distinctly select all values from that series that are between the start and end dates on the main table:

```
CREATE TABLE my_data (
  start_date DATE,
  end_date DATE
 );
 INSERT INTO my_data (start_date, end_date) VALUES
 ('2018-08-01 00:00:00+00', '2018-08-05 00:00:00+00'),
 ('2018-08-03 00:00:00+00', '2018-08-05 00:00:00+00'),
 ('2018-08-09 00:00:00+00', '2018-08-10 00:00:00+00');

SELECT DISTINCT all_dates.dates
FROM (
  SELECT dates.d AS dates
  FROM generate_series(
    (SELECT MIN(start_date) FROM my_data),
    (SELECT MAX(end_date) FROM my_data),
    '1 day'::interval
  ) AS dates(d)
) AS all_dates
INNER JOIN my_data
    ON all_dates.dates BETWEEN my_data.start_date AND my_data.end_date
ORDER BY all_dates.dates;
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nF1oXaXk8EJF8NuHBz1Fig/0)